# Load text file with placeholders in python

Tags: python, yaml

I am developing an installer and I need to create a settings file written in YAML. This file has some placeholders that need to fill with data provided by the user.
The code where I read the file is as follows:

```
f = open ('settings.py', 'w +')
settings = open (path + '/ settings_model.yaml', 'r').read()
settings% (user_var)
f.write (settings)
f.close ()
```

And the settings_model.yaml file is something like:

"" "PATH = '% s'" ""

When I run the script, the placeholder is not filled

"" "PATH = '% s'" ""

How I can do to achieve that placeholder filled correctly?

Comment: looks like the third line should be `settings = settings % (user_var)`. Or without the parentheses.

Comment: of course you have to assign the result of the operation back to the settings variable `settings = settings % user_var`

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, I would say you need to assign the result of your %-operation somewhere:

```
settings = settings % user_var
```

In stead of

```
settings% (user_var)
```

(the `()` around the user_var make no difference, if you want it to be a tuple, use `(user_var, )`, but this is besides the point, both should work).

Somehow the whole thing doesn't feel very safe or secure, but you only asked for a fix of your code ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem was that the contents of the settings file was wrapped in quotes. Moreover I also pass over to assignment after modifying the variable settings.